# Writing Grid 2d array to file using XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, grid, monogame

I have got a huge 2d array which looks like

```
Map grid = new int[,] { {1,1,1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0},{2,2,2,2,2,2}};
```

i use it do describe a grid for a monogame project.
I am creating a level editor for the game i am developing,
the level editor needs to write the new grid which will be created after using the level editor, to an external file.
i was recommended to use XML for writing my grid to the external file.
later , i will have to read the file and send the data to a new 
Map grid constructor.

I am new to XML , and havent found a good working way for writing it correctly.
I am using visual studio community 2017 , C# .
Thanks alot for any help !

Comment: You write your data to XML like you would write any other data to XML: You come up/define a XML data structure/layout (or are given a XML data structure/layout you need to adhere to), and then write/serialize the data according to that XML data structure. I can't say anything more, since i don't know about the XML data structure you want/need to use and thus don't really know exactly what you would mean by saying "_writing it correctly_". **_Edit_** and improve your question, adding information about the XML data structure you want to write, and your XML-related code you were trying...

Comment: The code below worked perfect, I am sorry for not giving too many details . what i needed actually is to run a loop over my 2d array and write it to file. now what i need is to read it back to an int[,]

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know why XML was recommended to you?  There are other file formats that would be better suited to this both in terms of size, speed and implementation complexity.

Comment: Well , maybe you are right . However, isnt it easier to split your text file by tags / attribites / id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication110
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] grid = new int[,] { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 } };

            string xml = "<Data></Data>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement data = doc.Root;

            for (int row = 0; row <= grid.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
            {
                XElement xRow = new XElement("Row");
                data.Add(xRow);
                for (int col = 0; col <= grid.GetUpperBound(1); col++)
                {
                    XElement xCol = new XElement("Column", grid[row, col]);
                    xRow.Add(xCol);
                }
            }
            data.Add(new XElement("music", new object[] {
                new XElement("GEVAs_main_sountrack"),
                new XElement("RonWalking")            
            }));
            doc.Save(FILENAME);

            XDocument newDoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            int[][] newGrid = newDoc.Descendants("Row").Select(x => x.Elements("Column").Select(y => (int)y).ToArray()).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW! thanks you ! works amazing i am so greatfull :)

Comment: Give me sample of XML file.

Comment: <Data>
  <Row>
    <Column>1</Column>
    <Column>1</Column>
    <Column>1</Column>
    <Column>1</Column>
    <Column>1</Column>
    <Column>1</Column>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Column>0</Column>
    <Column>0</Column>
    <Column>0</Column>
    <Column>0</Column>
    <Column>0</Column>
    <Column>0</Column>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Column>2</Column>
    <Column>2</Column>
    <Column>2</Column>
    <Column>2</Column>
    <Column>2</Column>
    <Column>2</Column>
  </Row>
  <music>
    <GEVAs_main_sountrack />
    <RonWalking />
  </music>
</Data>

Comment: https://imgur.com/AOrsiJK   thats a link to the image !( example of xml)

Comment: Man thank you i already have that , i need to read the file into an array for the grid , others go to a string :)

Comment: You are amazing! Thx alot :)

Comment: The original array and new array are different.  Original is [,] and new is [][].

Comment: and is it possible to make it as the original one ?

Comment: If you are using linq, then it is better to change original array to [][].  Using [,] I think is really obsolete with Net Library and is only included to be backwards compatible to older code.  New designs should use [][].

Comment: ok thanks i understand , and how can i store the values inside <music> into a string[] ?

Comment: Is string a one dimensional array or two dimensional array.  To convert a integer array to a string use string join method :            int[][] myArray = new int[][] { new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4 , 5 }, new int[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 } };
            string[] str = myArray.Select(x => string.Join(",", x)).ToArray();

Comment: I meant that i need the texts values from the xml file inside <music> tag , to store inside strings at my program :) –

Comment: Start with : XElement xMusic = newDoc.Descendants("music").First();  Then use (string)xMusic.Element("GEVAs_main_sountrack") to get innertext of a child and (string)xMusic.Descendents("RonWalking").First(); to get other properties.

Comment: This is too complicated, use the XmlSerializer instead.

Comment: Serializer should not be used in every case especially when you want a two dimensional table and the xml is multi level.